# How to batch rename files with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have 14,000 pictures sorted into files by year and month but taken with multiple cameras. I want the file name to reflect the date taken. All of my pictures are .jpg.

For example all pictures taken on October 16, 1998 are in a folder directory called

```
..\1998\10 October\1998 10 16\
```

I want the all the pictures to be named `19981016_0001.jpg`,  `19981016_0002.jpg` etc.

I can get to the point where it list the folder I want to change. But I'm unable to actually change it. I created a temp file of copies in case I messed it up. I started by typing

```
cd "C:\Documents and Settings\Brooke LastName\Desktop\Temp
```

then after successfully getting my file to load I used a formula I found on this site.

```
ls *jpg | Foreach {$i=1} {Rename-Item _ -NewName ("$($.19981016){0:00000000#} .jpg" -f $i++) -whatif}
```

The error I got said

```
Unexpected token ' .19981016' in expression or statement.  
At line:1 char:12 + $.19981016 <<<<
```

I found several formulas on the web, but most created files that would number with parenthesis for example `vacation (1).jpg`. I want a four digit counter `0001` after an underscore at the end of my date.

Could someone help me out and give me dummy instructions? I have zero programming knowledge.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to SuperUser.

Comment: I'm sorry if I posted in the wrong place. SuperUser? Where should I post this question?

Comment: Crap I already did. I searched this site for superuser and found a link. I didn't realize they were connected. I've spent all day on this so I was hoping I was asking a simple question. Sorry.

Comment: @Brooke No harm done, I'll migrate and flag for merger.

Comment: @Brooke Please check, if I edited too much and roll back if needed. Are all pictures in folders with this name scheme: `19981016`? So can the script always take the name of the folder one level up and just append a 4-digit counter to the name?

Comment: Thank you! Yes it all looks correct except I leave spaces in my file folder names between the year, month and date. I don't want spaces on my file names. I was going to do each file one date at a time but if I could run all of my pictures that would be great as well. Thanks for responding.